# Иммутабельность через store commit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, state

Всем привет,у меня есть такая вот иммутабельность

```
data() {
      return {
        photo: clone(this.$store.state.photo.photoInfo),
      };
    },
```

Как сделать это не тут,а через commit store?,вот мой стор

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  state: {
    photoInfo: [
      {leftFront: "",title:'Спереди слева', url: ""},
      {leftBack: "",title:'Сзади слева', url: ""},
      {rightFront: "",title:'Спереди справа', url: ""},
      {rightBack: "",title:'Сзади справа', url: ""},
      {around: "",title:'Круговое', url: ""},
      {vin: "",title:'Фото VIN кода', url: ""},
      {odo: "",title:'Фото показаний одометра при включенном зажигании (при наличии ключей от ТС) ', url: ""},
      {rear: "",title:'Фото задней части салона', url: ""},
      {front: "",title:'Фото передней части салона', url: ""},
      {tires: "",title:'Фото шин и дисков', url: ""},
      {inside: "",title:'Фото подкапотного пространства', url: ""}
    ]
  },
  actions:{
   loadFile({ commit }, file) {
         const { name } = file;
         const formData = new FormData();
         formData.append(name, file);
         formData.append('name', 'files');
         axios.post('api/v1/files/create', {
           count: 11,
         })
           .then(() => axios.put('api/v1/files', formData));
       },
    savePhotorForm ({ commit }, info) {
      console.log(info);
      commit('setPhoto', info)
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPhoto (state, payload) {
      state.photoInfo = payload
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Сделайте через геттер в сторе, в чем вопрос?

Comment: А по подробнее?)

Answer (score 0):

В state добавляем:

```
  getters: {
    storePhoto (state) {
      return state.photoInfo
    }
  }
```

В компоненте:

```
  computed: {
    photo () {
      return this.$store.getters.storePhoto
    }
  }
```

После этого в сторе делайте что хотите и в любой компоненте получайте данные.

ps можно получать в помпоненте и так

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'storePhoto'
    ])
}
```